# WebBrowserコントロールのWebBrowserReadyState.Completeを待ちたい

Tags: c#, winforms

C#初心者です。
WebBrowserコントロールを使用して、PCの起動時刻を会社の勤怠入力画面にセットする処理を自動化したいと考えています。
勤怠入力画面はURLは同じまま遷移するので、WebBrowser1.Navigateは初回のみで、その後は画面内のHTML要素を取得して特定の要素にクリックイベントを発生させながら処理を進めています。
クリックイベント発生後のページ読み込み完了は、以下のように取得しています。

```
WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://test.net/");
HtmlWindow iframe = WebBrowser1.Document.Window.Frames[2];
HtmlElementCollection elements = iframe.Document.All;
HtmlElement dgrdSubMenu = elements.GetElementsByName("commit")[0];
dgrdSubMenu.InvokeMember("click");

if (WaitReadyState())
{
    (後続処理)
}

public bool WaitReadyState()
{
    bool rtnFlg = true;
    int i = 1;
    int maxTry = 20;

    while (WebBrowser1.IsBusy || metsWebBrowser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
    {
        Application.DoEvents();
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        i++;

        if (i >= maxTry)
        {
            rtn = false;
            rtnFlg = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return rtnFlg;
}
```

このコードは期待通りに動作はしているのですが、Application.DoEvents()は使うべきではないという情報を見たことと、実際にここでApplication.DoEvents()をすることによる弊害が出ているため、非同期処理への置き換えをしたいです。

下記のコードは私の要望を満たすものに見えますが、「Wait here for the completed event to fire.」の部分に何を入れるべきか分からずにいます。

<相談>
　・類似のQAは複数ヒットしますが、質問した箇所が「WebBrowser1.Navigate(url)」となっている回答例ばかりで、私のコードのようにクリックイベントを行った後のCompletedを取得する方法を教えてください。
　・サイトはiFrameが使われており、全ての読み込みが完了したことを取得したいです。
　・必須ではありませんが、CompletedならTrue、タイムアウトならfalseが返せるとベターです。この場合、WebBrowserの処理全体に対するタイムアウトではなく、foo()メソッド（つまり1ページ毎の読み込み）に対してタイムアウト処理が指定できると嬉しいです。

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26959655/is-there-an-application-doevents-for-webbrowser

```
async Task<int[]> foo()
{
    //Create the completion source and the callback delegate.
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
    WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler callback = (sender, args) => tcs.SetResult(null);

    //Subscribe to the Document completed event and run the callback.
    browser.DocumentCompleted += callback;

    try
    {
        //We may already be in the complete state so the event will never fire.
        //Therefor if we are in the completed state we can skip the await.
        if (browser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
        {
            //Wait here for the completed event to fire.
            await tcs.Task;
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        //Unsubscribe the callback which is nolonger needed.
        browser.DocumentCompleted -= callback;
    }

    //Process the data from the completed document.
    var data = extract_data();
    return data;
}
```

Comment: どうしてもWebBrowserコントロールでなければならない理由が無ければ、WebView2に移行することをお勧めします。[Microsoft Edge WebView2 の概要](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/microsoft-edge/webview2/) 要望されることはだいたい出来るでしょう。

Comment: @kunif ありがとうございます。対象サイトがIE互換モードでしか動かず、WebBrowserコントロールを使う必要があるんです…。信じがたいのですが、IE5互換のようです。

Comment: メソッド等の内部でループして待つとか、特定の目的のために1つのメソッドの中でイベントハンドラを登録/解除するとかではなく、処理に相応しい種類の何かのTimerイベントハンドラ等でReadyStateプロパティの状態をチェックして必要な状態になった時に必要な処理を行えば良いのではありませんか？ そしてTimerイベントハンドラなので同時にTimeoutチェックを組み込むのも簡単でしょう。

Comment: @kunif timerイベントハンドラの実装イメージが完全に理解できているか怪しい上でのコメントですが、その方法では結局Application.DoEventsを無くすことが出来ないのではないかと思います。WebBrowserコンポーネントでループでReadyStateをチェックする場合、DoEventsしないと状態の変化を取れないためです。

Comment: まあその辺を理解するには知識と経験を重ねる必要があるでしょうね。ループやDoEventsは不要でしょう。Timerイベントハンドラは言わばそれらを実行しているランタイムから呼ばれている状態ですので。

Comment: WaitReadyState メソッドから Application.DoEvents(); を削除したうえで、Task.Run を利用して WaitReadyState メソッドをUI スレッドとは別のスレッドで実行し、それを await で待機するようにしたらどうなりますか？

Comment: 現在のコードベースだと、webbrowserコントロールはApplication.Doeventsなしに表示中のページの状態を更新しないため、その非同期処理は終わらなくなります。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ・サイトはiFrameが使われており、全ての読み込みが完了したことを取得したいです。

ページの読み込み完了を取得するには、WebBrowser.DocumentCompleted イベントを使用すると良いです。
ただし、ページ及びページ内の iframe 読み込み完了時にもイベントが発火するので、イベント引数 WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs.Url を参照して、どのページの読み込みが完了したかを確認します。イベントは、iframe、親ページの順に発火します。
WebBrowser.ReadyState で待機することもできますが、どのページの読み込みが完了したかを直接に知ることはできないので、WebBrowser.DocumentCompleted を使用するのが良いと思います。

> 私のコードのようにクリックイベントを行った後のCompletedを取得する方法を教えてください。

WebBrowser.DocumentCompleted イベントは、親ページ内の操作による読み込み完了時には、発火しますが、今回のように、iframe 内の操作時には、発火しません。(WebBrowser.ReadyState も Complete のまま変化しません。)代わりに、iframe の onload イベントを追加することで、iframe 内の操作による iframe 内ページの読み込み完了を取得できます。読み込み完了を監視したい iframe を HtmlElement として取得し、HtmlElement.AttachEventHandler で、onload イベントを追加します。
ここで、iframe を HtmlWindow として取得し、HtmlWindow.AttachEventHandler で、onload イベントを追加することもできますが、この場合は、iframe 内の操作による iframe 内ページの読み込み完了を取得することはできません。この方法では、少なくとも私の環境では、onload が発火されませんでした。

以下は、これらの有効な方法で、目的の操作と思われる内容を実装したコードとなります。

```
private async Task RunMacro()
{
    // 対象ページの URL
    string targetPageUrl = "https://localhost:7267/";
    // 対象ページ内の iframe の ID
    string targetIframeId = "frmHeveyPage";            

    // 対象ページの読み込み完了フラグ
    bool isTargetPageCompleted = false;

    this.webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += (s, ev) =>
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"{ev.Url} DocumentCompleted");

        if (ev.Url.ToString() != targetPageUrl)
        {
            // 対象ページ読み込み完了時 (iframe の読み込みも完了)
            isTargetPageCompleted = true;
            return;
        }
    };

    // 対象ページへ移動
    this.webBrowser1.Navigate(targetPageUrl);
    Debug.WriteLine($"Navigate {targetPageUrl}");

    // 対象ページの読み込み完了を待機
    while (!isTargetPageCompleted) 
    {                
        await Task.Delay(1000);
    }

    // 対象 iframe 読み込み完了フラグ
    bool isIframeCompleted = false;

    // iframe を HTML Element として取得
    // (*) HtmlWindows として取得すると onload がフックできない
    var iframeHtmlElement = this.webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById(targetIframeId);

    iframeHtmlElement.AttachEventHandler("onload", (se, evt) =>
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"ifrme loaded.");
        isIframeCompleted = true;
    });

    // 対象 iframe を HtmlWindows として取得
    var iframe = this.webBrowser1.Document.Window.Frames
        .Cast<HtmlWindow>().FirstOrDefault(f => f.Name == targetIframeId);
    // iframe 内のボタンの取得
    var btn = iframe.Document.All.GetElementsByName("btnReload")[0];
    // Click イベントの発火
    btn.InvokeMember("click");
    Debug.WriteLine($"Button click.");

    while (!isIframeCompleted)
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
    }

    //TODO: iframe 読み込み完了時の処理
    Debug.WriteLine("ロード完了後の処理");
}
```

DocumentCompleted, AttachEventHandler をクロージャーで定義し、while ループで、発火まで待機しています。
タイムアウトを設定したい場合は、while ループ内で、経過時間をカウントして、既定のタイムアウト時間を超えたときは、break でループを抜ける処理を入れると良いと思います。

Comment: おりがとうございます！この問題、どれだけ調べでも分からなかったので本当に助かります。残念ながら私のアカウントの状態ではポイントを付与できないようで、申し訳ありません。

Comment: @okaken もし信用度の付与のことを指していらっしゃるのであれば、回答を承認すると回答者に信用度が与えられます。ヘルプページはこちらです: https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers